# attempt to index nil with 'LocalPlayer'

Tags: lua, roblox

so basically i was making a power up script until its error showed up:  Workspace.Part.Script:5: attempt to index nil with 'LocalPlayer'. Also im new to all of this so i dont really have the best clue on why this happened.

heres the script:

`

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.MaxHealth = math.huge 
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = math.huge 
        Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 36
        Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.JumpPower = 10
    end
end)
```

`

To be honest not much. I tweaked some grammar and stuff nothing helped though.

```
type here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.MaxHealth = math.huge 
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = math.huge 
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 36
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.JumpPower = 10
    end
end)
```